# Spark read S3 path with "/" as prefix

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have source data at S3 path like:

```
s3://mybucket/prefix1/prefix2//prefixX/prefixY/partitionColumn=2023/
```

I need to create Data frame to read
`s3://mybucket/prefix1/prefix2//prefixX/prefixY/` but I am getting

```
"Path does not exist: s3://mybucket/prefix1/prefix2/prefixX/prefixY/".
```

The reason being it does not recognise the prefix with "/" in between.

> df = spark.read.json("s3://mybucket/prefix1/prefix2//prefixX/prefixY/")

Can anyone help to read path having above folder structure?

Expecting to create df with given S3 folder path.

Comment: What is the double-slash meant to represent?

Answer (score 0):

spark and the filesystem connectors it uses to object stores contain assumptions that they are working with a hierarchical filesystem with directories, subdirectories etc.

AWS is an object store and if you try hard you can get a bucket into a state where spark can't work with the data.

Examples

- creating objects under objects; listing may/may not find them
- creating objects with /./ or /../ in their keys
- creating objects with // in their keys
  plus more.

If you do that, expect rdd scans to miss data, path resolution problems, loss of data when renaming, deletion of parent files with /  as their suffix, ....

you have just managed to create one of the failure conditions. Fix: use a "valid" path within the metaphor of a hierarchical directory structure.